# Amazon S3 static website - Redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm about to launch a static website using S3/Cloudfront. I don't need HTTPS for the site, but the current iteration of the website is served over HTTPS and has hundreds of links and indexed URLs that are HTTPS.

I've been searching for hours and can't find a way to redirect our HTTPS URLs to HTTP when only using S3/Cloudfront. Currently the HTTPS URL will refuse the connection instead of redirecting to the HTTP version of the page.

With no Apache it seems it is not possible to do this. Any hints?

Answer (score 27):

Static website hosting on S3 does not support HTTPS unless you use the full domain path, i.e.  `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  Since you want to keep your URL, you'll have to use a CloudFront distribution to handle SSL.

1. Upload your SSL certificate to CloudFront:
   `aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name CertificateName --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key file://privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain_file --path /cloudfront/path/` [1]
2. Create a cloudfront distribution and configure as so:

   - **Origin Domain Name**: your s3 bucket's public static website hosting endpoint (not the endpoint that CloudFront autocompletes)
   - **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)**: desired location for your website, e.g. example.com or www.example.com
   - **SSL Certificate**: Select the SSL certificate you uploaded in step 1.
   - **Custom SSL Client Support**: Unless you need compatibility for really old clients, select "Only Clients that support Server Name Indication" and save $600.

   If you are redirecting https to s3 redirect, the origin domain should not be the autocomplete bucket, but the static redirect endpoint s3 gives you
3. Save your distribution.  It should show Status "In Progress".  It generally takes ~15 minutes before a distribution is "Deployed"; don't move on to step 4 until your distribution is "Deployed".
4. Verify the distribution works: navigate to the CloudFront distribution via the domain name in the list, e.g. "https//d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/".  You should see your website.
5. Change your DNS records to point to the CloudFront distribution instead of the S3 bucket.

[1] if you have trouble adding your certificate to CloudFront check out this article for further information:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#cnames-and-https-procedure

Comment: This is probably the most viable approach without deploying your own server or proxy, since an HTTPS server will not even *see* the incoming request (in order to be able to redirect it) unless the certificate is valid or the user bypasses the security warning.  Cloudfront with SNI will not redirect the https links to http, but it will make them work as https, for most browsers.

Comment: hey guys, I had a similar problem where i wanted to redirect apex http to https, using an ALIAS a record to s3 redirect, but was having problems when the user manually tried to type an apex https. So i followed these steps to install my ssl on a CF but was getting  "access denied" when trying this solution. I finally figured it out by modifying step #2. The origin domain should not be the autocomplete bucket, but the static redirect endpoint s3 gives you.

Comment: Can verify that this setup does work and allows you to configure an apex domain to redirect for both http:// and https:// using S3 Static Website Hosting + Redirect All Request. 

The 2 alterations I needed to make to get the setup to work was A) @RyanRomanchuk 's call out to use the **static website endpoint URL** `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` for origin (lifesaver, ty) and B) Setting the `Origin Protocol Policy` to be `HTTP Only`.

Also, during setup, remember to wait for settings updates to deploy and use cache invalidations if undesired responses were cached.

Comment: @KenColton Did you mean `HTTPS Only`? There is no option for `HTTP Only` and also why not redirect http to https

Comment: @jamylak it's from Cloudfront https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871468/https-for-s3-bucket-with-redirection

Comment: Also I found this in the CloudFront docs "If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured as a website endpoint, you must specify HTTP Only. Amazon S3 doesn't support HTTPS connections in that configuration." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Works from the CloudFront URL, but not from my domain.