# HTTPS for S3 bucket with redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website on *example.com*. I have created a S3 bucket and set it up to redirect all requests to *example.com* and I have created a DNS entry to point *www.example.com* to that S3 bucket. So far, redirecting from *http://www.example.com* --> *http://example.com* works fine

I am having trouble redirecting *https* traffic from *https://www.example.com* --> *https://example.com*.

I have created a Cloudfront distribution and added SSL to it and pointed it to the S3 bucket mentioned above. When I try to access that distribution given domain name, instead of being redirected I am getting the following in browser:

```xml
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Name>www.example.com</Name>
  <Prefix/>
  <Marker/>
  <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
  <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
</ListBucketResult>
```

My distribution general settings are

```
Distribution ID XXXXXXXXXXXX
Log Prefix  -
Delivery Method Web
Cookie Logging  Off
Distribution Status Deployed
Comment -
Price Class Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)
AWS WAF Web ACL -
State   Enabled
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) -
SSL Certificate mycert
Domain Name xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
Custom SSL Client Support   Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)
Default Root Object -
Last Modified   2016-01-18 16:12 UTC+2
Log Bucket
```

Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are close.  CloudFront is the correct solution.

Instead of selecting the bucket from the drop-down, you need a slightly different approach.

In the redirecting bucket's [static web site hosting configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ConfiguringBucketWebsite.html), find the **endpoint**.  This will be in a form similar to `bucket-name.s3-website.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com`.

Use this hostname, instead of selecting the bucket from the drop-down list.

> When you specify the bucket name in this format, you can use Amazon S3 redirects and Amazon S3 custom error documents.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

Note also that your [Origin Protocol Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy), which specifies the protocol used between CloudFront and S3, must be set to HTTP Only.  (This setting is back-end only, the front-end can still be https).

Comment: You are a lifesaver ! Selecting the bucket from the dropdown doesn't work for redirecting. You have to give it the s3-website url.

Comment: Also don't forget to invalidate "/*" your CloudFront to see the effect.

Comment: It's a shame that AWS didn't include this in their doc. Still confusing in 2022.